# Window.open() opens raw text instead of actual file

Tags: angular, typescript, blob, fileapi

In Angular app when I try to open a blob file received from the api using the following method in Chrome or Edge browser, a new tab opens with raw text instead of the corresponding file.

```
  static openFileInTab = (blob: Blob) => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  };
```

or

```
  static openFileInTab = (blob: Blob) => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = url;
    anchor.target = '_blank';
    anchor.click();
  };
```

In Firefox both of the following methods work correctly, but not in Chrome/Edge.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Try setting appropriate mime type one the blob. If you don't know the exact type, try using octet-stream.

Comment: @TotallyNewb My api returns all files with content-type `application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8`.
The only way to distinguish the file type is to read the extension from the content-disposition header

Comment: That's strange, I can't seem to reproduce this behavior if the blob has properly set type. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xfx13c - it seems to correctly save the file in both chromium and gecko based browsers.

Comment: Yes, the download works but I don't want to download the file, I want to open a preview of it in a new tab, the user will decide for themselves if they want to save the file.

Comment: well that might come down to the browser settings. if you want it to open it should probably in html/text, you might want to wrap the text in a body, but you can try with a mine/type first on its own.